# Is it possible to view all 'To-do's in all my boards?

Tags: trello-boards

I want to view all "to do" or "doing" categories in my all boards.
My goal is to view all "to do" items in one big picture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @BobbyGrace , I believe he means Lists. 'To Do' and 'Doing' lists are provided by default in a Trello board

Answer (score 1):

The cards page is probably your best bet. See: https://trello.com/my/cards. It lists all cards assigned to you across all boards. It will sort by list, so if "To-do" is leftmost on the board, those cards will show up first. There is no way to filter by list on the cards page at the moment.